# is there any way to debug movesense device without movesense programmer?

Tags: movesense

I'm developing a product using a Movesense sensor. But I don't have a Movesense programmer. Currently, I'm using the DFU method to update the latest firmware. The issue I'm facing is I can't see the logs of the Movesense device. And that is why I don't know which part of my program isn't working correctly or where I made a mistake. So is there any way that I can see the logs?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community he asked it plain and simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question. What I am doing now is:

- Use the adbbridge app found here https://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/tools/
- You can then add some debug info logs to your code for example:  `DebugLogger::info("readTemperatureFromSensor() idx: %u", idx);`

Then

1. Open the movesense adb bridge app and connect to the sensor
2. Use as instructed on the link above the commend to connect to the logs of the Android device and get the info: `adb logcat | grep OUTPUT`
3. Make the sensor do what you have programmed it for. If its whiteboard subscribe etc or some ble action.
4. Then subscribe also to the debug logs for example `python_client % adb shell am broadcast -a "android.intent.action.MOVESENSE"  --es type subscribe --es path System/Debug/Verbose --es value '''{}''' --es id 2`

2 and 3 are interchangeable of course.

PS. Make sure your app is build with the debug module as well

ie:
`OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(DebugService, true)`

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jimmy. As soon as I check this, I'll contact you if I need assistance.